# c# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' (CS0029)

Tags: c#, string, image, controls

i am currently writing a program that allows users to view multiple transparent images ontop of one another, they are able to toggle 6 different images on or off.

To explain how it works:

Image 1 is always the background (unless its toggled off in which case the next 'on' image is the background)

for example:

- if image 1 is ON and image 2 is ON then image 2 uses image 1 as its parent.
- if image 1 is ON, image 2 is OFF and image 3 is ON then image 3 will use Image 1 as its parent

etc

To achieve this i created an array - imageName[6]. When an image is turned on the corresponding element (e.g. image 1 = imageName[0]) says [image1].

Using this method i was hoping to create a control which would change the 'parent' of an image based on the example shown above.

I thought using the following code would work:

```
imageB.parent = imageName[0]
```

//This is just an example, the required answer would be     imageB.parent = imageA
//I need to achieve this answer using the data in the array.

but i just get the error message listed in the title:

(Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' (CS0029) )

Could anyone help me with this problem? Im afraid im stumped.

Please note, my code is alot more complicated then this, the above just shows a small snippet of it rather then displaying all 776 lines of my code xD

**UPDATE:**
To summarise, i need to assign an images parent based on the name stored in part of my array (in this case [0] ie [image1]

The error im having makes this impossible,

Is there a way to solve this or am i just writing very bad code?

Comment: `factionLayersID[0]` is a `string` based on the error message, you need to be setting the parent to an actual control object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string which is  `factionLayersID[0]` and you are trying to assing it a `Control` variable.That's why you are getting that exception.

Your  array elements type should be `Control`. Like this:

```
Control[] factionLayers = new Control[6];
```

Then you can assign your element to parent control:

```
imageB.parent = factionLayers[0]
```

Comment: Sorry i edited my post before reading this but i think i understand what your saying, so i need to set my array as a control array when its first declared?

Comment: yes, and you should store your control variable in that array

Comment: Thanks for the help, i figured it out based on this answer :-)